# Mangeto Admin and website display changed after changing web section in config, Magento 1.X

Tags: magento-1.9

I was trying to optimize my magento site and for that I made a few changes within my admin section:

First under :

System > Config > Web > Session Cookie Management

I had set the  Cookie Domain  to "www.semipreciousking.com" which was blank earlier, and I also made changes to:

System > Config > Web > Secure > Base Media URL

I changed this section to the CNAME which I created for static content,

earlier it was like this:

{{secure_base_url}}media/

I changed it to this:

https://www.image.semipreciousking.com/media/

Since I created and CNAME of image.semipreciousking.com, and someone mentioned to do it this way and I did, but as soon as I made changes, the admin panel and the site display changed and the save button in admin panel has stopped functioning because of which I was unable to redo all the changes. All the media files within the site and the admin section have stopped functioning because of that.

Can you please help me with that?

Will really appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can redo all changes directly from your database 'core_config' table

Answer (score 0):

To remove the cookie domain setting run the following query in the database

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = NULL WHERE path 'web/cookie/cookie_domain';
```

To reset your media URLs run:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = '{{unsecure_base_url}}media/' WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_media_url';
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = '{{{{secure_base_url}}media/' WHERE path = 'web/secure/base_media_url';
```

Once you've run both of them make sure you clear your cache.